# How to read and process NSQ messages with existing Flask application properly?

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, tornado, pynsq

So my problem is:

1. I have existing Flask application that has several Celery periodic tasks (so Flask app running and Celery workers for process tasks are running).

Now in our infrastructure appears [NSQ](http://nsq.io/) and 3rd application that pushes messages to NSQ, so I have to add functionality to existing Flask app that can read those messages from NSQ and do some work (probably create entities in DB or initiate Celery tasks)

2. I looked at [pynsq](https://pynsq.readthedocs.io) official client, it based on tornado.IOLoop, so it requires that IOLoop is started all time, the example from documentation works well, but I don't have an idea how to run Reader with existing Flask app in one thread.
3. I looked ad [gnsq](https://github.com/wtolson/gnsq) library that based on gevent, it seems possible to start its Reader in separate thread.

So possible ways to do smth I see:

1. Probably run Reader (run_forever) in separate thread, so when Reader founds message - some work I can delegate to callback handler function that starts on_message event.
2. Probably exists way when I can read messages from queue and process it, for example from Celery task, that I run once in 30 sec. But I cannot find how, all libraries I saw provide long-polling way, when Reader starts like infinite loop and reads messages.
3. Make separate application that will be responsible for reading messages from NSQ and re-use some code from existing Flask app in it. (or just make that application like 'portal' from NSQ to my Flask app).

P.S.  I've tried to start Reader in thread when Flask app starts, I got some success with [gnsq](https://github.com/wtolson/gnsq) library, its Reader connects to NSQ and on message runs handler's code,  but with pynsq that based on IOLoop - when I'm trying to run nsq.run() in thread it fails, seems I cannot to run "pynsq" nsq.run() not in main thread)

Please point me in right direction, I'm stuck a bit how to make it properly.

P.S. Also probably somebody can give me advice of proper way to read messages from NSQ from synchronous code, I mean for example when some code starts in celery task, in that code can I read and process NSQ messages somehow ?

Comment: Now I close to use **nsq_to_http** binary from NSQ distribution - to push my Flask service by HTTP REST and pass message body to Flask message handler.

Comment: You can [integrate flask and tornado with tornado's WSGI wrapper](https://gist.github.com/andreif/6088558). It will proxy requests to Flask when IOLoop is idle and read messages from NSQ when Flask is idle. Your 3rd approach (microservices) is fine too: receive messages using separate app and pass it to Flask via http.

Comment: @Fian thank you for answer. I saw possibility to use tornado's WSGI wrapper, but as I understood there possible performance degradation. So now I focused on usage [nsq_to_http](http://nsq.io/components/utilities.html#nsq_to_http) binary that is provided with NSQ distribution. **nsq_to_http** pushes my Flask's app API endpoint, so I can process it in Flask app successfully.